# HTML5 datalist in Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, html-datalist

I have an HTML5 datalist working in Chrome (desktop) but when using the same input in Android and the latest Chrome, auto-completion no longer works.

Is this feature not supported by Chrome in Android?

Comment: Can you try this in the latest M25 Beta

Comment: I tried it out but receive non of the suggestions from my datalist. Using a Motorola Xoom

Answer (score 1):

Desktop Chrome have supported  since version 20, and Android Chrome is still version 18.

Answer (score 1):

The `datalist` suggestion UI was implemented in Chrome for Android v33.